# Mysql combining two queries

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select sira, count(sira) c from mesajlar
group by sira
order by c desc
limit 20;

SELECT `baslik` FROM `konular` WHERE `id` = ??SIRA??
```

I want to combine these two queries.

I have table named mesajlar and konular.
I want to get most common 20 values of 'sira' from mesajlar.
Then I want to use those values in second query.

How to do that?

Comment: What is the schema for the mesajlar and konular tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    konular.baslik
    ,m.c
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            sira,
            count(sira) c
        FROM
            mesajlar
        GROUP BY
            sira
        ORDER BY
            c DESC
        LIMIT 20
    ) m
        INNER JOIN konular
            ON konular.id = m.sira
```

Comment: That's working thank you. Is it possible to use this query in php?

Comment: Yes, its an SQL. You can use it in any programming language you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can I show 'c' with 'baslik' ? Can you tell me that I am a bit newbie with mysql